# A SINGLE Post Giving an "Under Maintenance" Message

Tags: errors, updates, 500-internal-error, maintenance

There is no hidden maintenance file to delete, the entire website is working fine except for 1 post. The post URL gives the message

> Briefly unavailable for scheduled maintenance. Check back in a minute.

Is there any way to figure out how to get rid of this? I've wiped the database and uploaded an UpDraft backup. Didn't do anything. I've tried to change the post's URL. This works, the post is viewable at this new url, but when I add a 301 redirect of the old url to the new one, it gets 'stopped' at the "Briefly unavailable for scheduled maintenance." page.

This post became unavailable when I updated some plugins. I've disabled every single plugin twice, and it did nothing.

Comment: What's the content of the page in question? Run [`wp_debug_backtrace_summary`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_debug_backtrace_summary/) on the page before / after the error and add those to your question.

Comment: @jonbon Can you add your `.htaccess` file contents in your question?